# For a given integer n, find the number following n that is a multiple of 10

Tags: visual-c++

For a given integer, *n*, find the number following *n* that is a multiple of 10.

I wrote code that seems to be correct, but the site reviewer writes that it is only 90% correct. What could be the problem?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n == 0) n = n + 10;
    while (n % 10 != 0) n++;
    cout << n;
}
```

Comment: Try it with `n = 10`. Do you get `20` printed out?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work if the given `n` is *itself* a multiple of 10, in which case it returns 'itself' rather than the *next* multiple of 10 (i.e. 1 in 10 possible cases = 90% success rate).

To fix this, increment the `n` *before* testing for a multiple of 10:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    while (++n % 10 != 0)
        ;
    std::cout << n;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can avoid the loop entirely. The following will work for both positive and negative numbers (it's a lot simpler if you don't cater for negative numbers):

```cpp
    n += ( n >= 0 ? 10 : 0 ) - (n % 10);
```

Comment: Yet another loop-less alternative is `10 * ((n >= 0) ? n / 10 + 1 : (n + 1) / 10)`.

Comment: @NikitaAndrukh Always happy to help - that's what Stack Overflow is for! Feel free to [explore how SO works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).‎